# В чём разница между созданием экземпляра модели через @classmethod и Manager

Tags: python, django, model

В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/) по Django приводится нижеследующая заметка:

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the **init**
>   method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
>   signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being
>   saved. Rather than overriding **init**, try using one of these
>   approaches:
>
> Add a classmethod on the model class:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
>     @classmethod
>     def create(cls, title):
>         book = cls(title=title)
>         # do something with the book
>         return book
>
> book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
> ```
>
> Add a method on a custom manager (usually preferred):
>
> ```
> class BookManager(models.Manager):
>     def create_book(self, title):
>         book = self.create(title=title)
>         # do something with the book
>         return book
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
>     objects = BookManager()
>
> book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")
> ```

Возможно подобный вопрос уже задавался, но всё же, в чём разница между созданием экземпляра модели через `@classmethod` и через `Manager`? Я хочу поглубже понять разницу между этими двумя подходами, и почему именно второй из них я является более предпочтительным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С позиции python - ни в чём. У вас есть класс, вы создаёте экземпляр и вызываете его метод.

С позиции django - тоже ни в чём. Вы создаёте экземпляр модели и сохраняете её.

В документации лишь показано, что вы можете так извернуться - через метод, а можете через менеджер. Но приоритетное использовать именно менеджер, потому что модель сама по себе не должна контролировать ни выборку элементов, ни создание. Она может лишь каким-то образом повлиять на сохранение (скажем, добавить время создание при вызове save) или запустить валидацию себя (вроде метода validate у модели, который, например, вызывается при валидации формой непротиворечивости данных, скажем, unique или unique_together - уникальность записей в бд).

Но созданием себя она не занимается. Этим занимается менеджер модели. Его наиболее используемая функция, конечно, выборка элементов, но в целом он ответственен за правильную передачу параметров уже в саму модель, выборку дополнительных полей по запросу и много за что ещё. Просто такова логика django, так обеспечивается модульность.

Можете для интереса заглянуть в [исходники создания пользователей в django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L136) - там как раз куча всяких параметров передаётся в модель. Представьте вы бы это всё в модель спихали. А то, что вы привели в документации - это простейший случай. Ну и в случае переопределения модели можно перетаскивать за собой методы создания и выборки экземпляров, например.